# python difference between two method of intersection(geometry)

Tags: python, pandas, geometry, geopandas

I'm a beginner of python. Before the question, sorry for my bad English.

I have two shapefiles(buildings - multipolygon, city - multipolygon)
I tried to intersect those two because I want to get information
of buildings location of city1.

I will show you two different code that I used.

```
import geopandas as gpd

sg = gpd.read_file('sg_4326/sg4326.shp')
sb = gpd.read_file('sb_4326/sb4326.shp')


sg = sg.rename(columns = {"EA002_NAM" : "gu_name"}) ##TO change index
sg.set_index("gu_name", inplace = True)
sg.sort()


sg_g = sg.geometry[u"광진구"] ##To get city1


mm = sb.geometry.intersects(sg_g) ##Intersects sb(buildings) and sg_g(city1)
mm[mm == 1]
```

And the oher one is

```
import geopandas as gpd

sg = gpd.read_file('sg_4326/sg4326.shp')
sb = gpd.read_file('sb_4326/sb4326.shp')


sg = sg.rename(columns = {"EA002_NAM" : "gu_name"}) ##TO change index name

sg_g = sg[sg["gu_name"] == u"광진구"] ##To get a city1


sg_g = sg_g.set_geometry("geometry", crs = {"init" : "epsg : 4326"})##TO set crs
sb = sb.set_geometry("geometry", crs = {"init" : "epsg : 4326"})


mm = sb.geometry.intersects(sg_g) #Intersect sb(buildings) and sg_g(city1)
mm[mm == 1]
```

I think different of those two is the type
upper one intersects `sg_g(shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon)` and `sb(geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame)`

other one is `sg_g(geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame)` and `sb(geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame)`

Output of first is all False(wrong) but second one is correct

1. Could you tell me the differences of two?
2. Is there any way to convert `(geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame)` to `(shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon)` at once?